# How to buffer PDF which is downloading and display it while dowloading using PDF Reader app in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I have to show a PDF from web. I had tried with Google Docs, but my PDF size is large (20mb or above),because of that Google Docs failed to display PDF. It is not a good way to download the PDF and display using PDF Reader, user has to wait for long time to see it.

My requirement is I have to display the PDF while downloading it in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever heard [Linearized PDF](http://mdn.morovia.com/manuals/pdfleo-1/PDF-Overview.php#Web-Optimized-Linearized-PDF)? Adobe reader displays first page with only a few hundreds bytes downloaded. You can use tools such as [PDFLeo](http://www.rockpdf.com) to convert to linearized PDF.

Comment: dude I want from application only it should call whatever pdfreader available in device , and display it.