# How to Display first page of PDF before downloading is completed

Tags: android, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to buffer pdf which is downloading and display it while dowloading using Pdf reader app in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415450/how-to-buffer-pdf-which-is-downloading-and-display-it-while-dowloading-using-pdf)

I am downloading PDF file from server and want to show it in android.

But my question is is pdf have many pages then how to display it before downloading completes.

I mean to say that i want to download it as well as show first page.
While user is going to read first page then other left pages should be download in background.

Comment: Render the first page as a bitmap, and display that, then kick off the download?

Comment: Extract the first page form the full pdf, Call it page 1 or preview or some such, download that and display while you are downloading the full fella in the background.

Comment: can you please suggest me some code to do this.please this is very urgent

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8415450/821436

Comment: while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       boolean flag = true;
       total += len1; // total = total + len1
       publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
       f.write(buffer, 0, len1);} but in this i am downloading pdf in SDDcard which i don't want to. because i got a problem when i get a file of about 58MB