# iOS display partial download of pdf, only first page

Tags: ios, pdf

Is it possible to display a pdf from a partial download?

I need only the first page of a pdf for my app. The problem is all the PDF online are 25mb or more in size. Optimizing for the app is not an option :(

The entire PDF will need to be downloaded to display and save it, but I want to show a preview first.

A similar question, but for android:
[How to Display first page of PDF before downloading is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549659/how-to-display-first-page-of-pdf-before-downloading-is-completed)

I do understand downloading of data in iOS, but how can I tell where in the PDF's data the page ends, so I can just display that.

Comment: Unless your pdfs are linearized, I.e. optimized for the early display of the first page, the data required to display it may be spread all over the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this but the PDF needs to be pre-constructed in a linearized format. This is something that is part of the PDF specfication and is sometimes known as fast-web-view.

Linearized PDF is the same as normal PDF but the objects in the document are ordered in a particular way and with certain extra information which makes it possible to work with partial data.

In particular the objects for the first page are included at the start of the file specifically so that the first page can be displayed quickly.

So I see no reason you shouldn't download the objects at the start of the PDF and use those to display the first page. You could use the hint tables for fast access to selected other pages but that would be quite complicated.

However the essence is that you need to pick up the group-one objects for the first page. These should run from the "%PDF" header through to the first "%%EOF". I'm not sure whether your environment will complain about the missing (but not required) objects but if it does you will need to blank them out on a binary level so that you have an internally consistent page one PDF.

For full details on PDF linearization see the Adobe PDF Specification.

My answers may feature concepts based around ABCpdf .NET. It's what I work on. It's what I know. :-)